# Clearing the standard input before reading while using the BufferedReader approach

Tags: java

I am trying to read from the standard input, using the `BufferedReader` (rather than Scanner) as suggested [here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-read-from-standard-input-in-java)

Not so infrequently the code seems to read a lingering newline character from the standard input that is causing the read logic to fail.

---

Q) What is the best way to flush the standard input prior to read?

Comment: Classic XY problem. What is your *actual* problem, and your *actual* code?

Answer (score 3):

X/Y problem (You have a problem X, and have imagined a solution Y and are now asking about Y, but you should really be asking/fixing X directly).

Flushing standard in is non-trivial. Fix whatever is causing random newlines to appear (most likely mixing scanner's `nextLine` and `nextAnythingElse`, which doesn't do the obvious thing and should be avoided).

You can write a utility method that calls `.readLine()` as normal, but will check if the received data is blank, and if so, calls readLine again, looping this process (`while`) until a non-blank line is received.